# как задать права на новые файлы директории Ubuntu Server 16.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

Здравствуйте.

При загрузке новых файлов через FTP, они становятся недоступными для сайта, nginx, apache, php...

**Реализовано это по следующему рецепту:**

Создадим нового пользователя для доступа через FTP

```
useradd -d /home/domain-name -s /sbin/nologin domain-name
```

Установим для него пароль

```
passwd domain-name
```

Создадим домашнюю директорию пользователя

```
mkdir -p /home/domain-name
```

Установим для нее права

```
chmod a-w /home/domain-name
```

Создадим группу для пользователя

```
groupadd ftps
```

Добавим пользователя в группу

```
usermod -G ftps domain-name
```

Поменяем владельца каталога

```
chown -R domain-name:ftps /home/domain-name
```

Создадим папку нашего сайта

```
mkdir /home/domain-name/domain-name.local
```

Сменим у нее владельца

```
chown -R domain-name:ftps /home/domain-name/domain-name.local
```

Смонтируем наши каталоги, откроем файл /etc/fstab

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

В самый низ вставим

```
/var/www/domain-name.local /home/domain-name/domain-name.local none bind 0 0
```

Добавим владельца /var/www/domain-name.local

```
chown www-data:domain-name /var/www/domain-name.local/ -R
```

Назначим права

```
find /var/www/domain-name.local -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find /var/www/domain-name.local -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

При загрузке новых файлов сервер отдает 403 ошибку...

Но если после загрузки написать:

```
find /var/www/domain-name.local -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find /var/www/domain-name.local -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

То файлы становятся доступными.

Как сделать чтобы при загрузке файлов они сразу были доступны для сайта?

Права но новых файлах:

Числовое значение: 600

-rw-------

Comment: кто кладет файлы туда? скорее всего это какой-то сервис, который от рута работает(скорее всего) либо от другого пользователья

Comment: и покажите до кучи права вновь созданных файлов.

Comment: @defrag, обновил.

Comment: Попробуйте заставить ftp сервер создавать файлы с нужной маской. например, Proftpd это делает с опцией: `Umask  002`

Comment: @defrag, большое спасибо, работает)))